# Análisis de XML: línea 1, carácter 72, punto y coma esperado

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedure

estoy revisando un procedimiento almacenado y obtengo este error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 72, semicolon expected.

cuando el debug esta por esta linea

`SET @CODSUCURSAL =  (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)'));`

esto es lo que hay dentro de `@PARAMETROS`:

`'01|12728056|10080|07/29/2021|HEY FRIENDS A&B|2|21|440|0|6.98|63|20'`

alguien podría ayudarme con esto ya que tengo conocimientos nulos en este tema

aquí el procedimiento almacenado completo:

```
DECLARE @CODSUCURSAL VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @CODEST NUMERIC(14);
DECLARE @CODTIPOINGRESO NUMERIC(10);
DECLARE @FECHAVEN VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @CONCEPTO VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @NCUOTA NUMERIC(3);
DECLARE @REFERENCIA VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @MONTO DECIMAL(12,2);
DECLARE @CODMONEDA NUMERIC(2);
DECLARE @TIPOCAMBIO DECIMAL(12,5);
DECLARE @CODDOC NUMERIC(12);
DECLARE @DESCUENTO DECIMAL(10,2);

DECLARE @PARAMETROS VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @TIPO INT;
DECLARE @ID BIGINT;
SET @PARAMETROS = (SELECT TOP 1  parametros from DBLAUXILIAR WHERE visto=0 ORDER BY id_solicitud asc);
SET @TIPO = (select TOP 1 tipo from DBLAUXILIAR WHERE visto=0 ORDER BY id_solicitud asc);
SET @ID = (select TOP 1 id_solicitud from DBLAUXILIAR WHERE visto=0 ORDER BY id_solicitud asc);
IF @TIPO = 1
    BEGIN
        EXEC REGISTROESTUDIANTE @PARAMETROS = @PARAMETROS , @ID = @ID; 
    END;
    IF @TIPO = 2
    BEGIN

    SET @CODSUCURSAL =  (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)'));
    SET @CODEST = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]', 'NUMERIC(14)'));
    SET @CODTIPOINGRESO = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]', 'NUMERIC(10)'));
    SET @FECHAVEN = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]', 'VARCHAR(50)'));
    SET @CONCEPTO = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[5]', 'VARCHAR(60)'));
    SET @NCUOTA = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[6]', 'NUMERIC(3)'));
    SET @REFERENCIA = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[7]', 'VARCHAR(10)'));
    SET @MONTO = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[8]', 'DECIMAL(12,2)'));
    SET @CODMONEDA = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[9]', 'NUMERIC(2)'));
    SET @TIPOCAMBIO = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[10]', 'DECIMAL(12,5)'));
    SET @CODDOC = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[11]', 'NUMERIC(12)'));
    SET @DESCUENTO = (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@PARAMETROS, '|', N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[12]', 'DECIMAL(10,2)'));
    
    Declare @ExecProcedure VARCHAR(1000);
    Declare @OUT INT;

    SET @ExecProcedure = '
    BEGIN
        cecnexsol.pkg_ing_mdw.p_GrabaIngreso (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); 
    END;';
    BEGIN TRY  
    EXEC (@ExecProcedure,
        @CODSUCURSAL,
        @CODEST,
        @CODTIPOINGRESO ,
        @FECHAVEN ,
        @CONCEPTO ,
        @NCUOTA ,
        @REFERENCIA ,
        @MONTO,
        @CODMONEDA ,
        @TIPOCAMBIO ,
        @CODDOC,
        @DESCUENTO) at [CECNEXSOL];
        select  @OUT = count(*) From [CECNEXSOL]..[CECNEXSOL].[V_EXCMLOG] Where ingnrodoc=@CODDOC AND exctipo='2' ;
        UPDATE DBLAUXILIAR SET visto =  1,resultado=@OUT WHERE id_solicitud = @ID;
    END TRY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te puedo ayudar directamente con el código, pero te puedo compartir una forma distinta de obtener los valores mediante un separador muy eficiente. El código se encuentra explicado en [este artículo](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). Pero de cualquier forma lo dejo aquí.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]  
--===== Define I/O parameters  
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS  
 RETURN  
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...  
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)  
  WITH E1(N) AS (  
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1  
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows  
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows  
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max  
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front  
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"  
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  
                ),  
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)  
                 SELECT t.N+1  
                   FROM cteTally t  
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)   
                )  
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.  
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),  
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))  
   FROM cteStart s  
;
```

Teniendo esa función en el sistema, el código que te está causando problemas puede quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT @CODSUCURSAL     = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  1 THEN s.Item END),
       @CODEST          = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  2 THEN s.Item END),
       @CODTIPOINGRESO  = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  3 THEN s.Item END),
       @FECHAVEN        = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  4 THEN s.Item END),
       @CONCEPTO        = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  5 THEN s.Item END),
       @NCUOTA          = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  6 THEN s.Item END),
       @REFERENCIA      = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  7 THEN s.Item END),
       @MONTO           = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  8 THEN s.Item END),
       @CODMONEDA       = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber =  9 THEN s.Item END),
       @TIPOCAMBIO      = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 10 THEN s.Item END),
       @CODDOC          = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 11 THEN s.Item END),
       @DESCUENTO       = MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 12 THEN s.Item END)
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@PARAMETROS, '|')s;
```

Comment: Buenísimo, gracias amigo esto es definitivamente mucho mejor

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en que tienes un carácter inválido en esa línea

`...A&B...`

Son carácteres inválidos en un documento XML los `&`, `<` y `>` (así como `"` o `'` en los atributos de una etiqueta), así que debes escaparlos antes de procesar el XML.
Tendrías que reemplazar `&` por `&amp;`, para tu error específico. Tendrás que controlar esto para `<` como `&lt;` y `>` como `&gt;`, etc.

Comment: gracias por responder amigo, me ayudaste a encontrar el error saludos .